# Exporting contents in html using java

Tags: java

I need to create an html page to export some information.

Currently, by using `java`, i've exported information to excel. But now, I need to export the information in `HTML` page using `Java`.Actually I am developing an application which will test rest api and generate the output in html.

Is there any APIs I can use? Thanks

Comment: I have seen it but i didn't got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that. You may use any template engine you like or write HTML directly.

- Freemarker (http://freemarker.org):  easy to use template engine
- Velocity: (https://velocity.apache.org/): another one
- XML + XSLT: Generate XML with `DocumentBuilder` or serialize your file with `XStream` and then apply XSLT. Safier (you can't miss tag) but only cool if you really like XSL (most people hate it).

If your app is web application, you may use `JSP` or `JSPX` which is part of servlet specification and good enoght (but its pain to use it offline, so only good for web apps)